# findFirstAsync() returns "invalid object" but findFirst() or findAllAsync() works

Tags: android, realm, android-livedata

I'm trying to create an async call to Realm using `findFirstAsync`.

```
Realm.getDefaultInstance().where<MyModel>().findFirstAsync()
```

But it always results in an "invalid object" (it does not crash but the returned object returns `false` on `isValid()`).

This is a problem because I want to use [LiveRealmObject](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/architectureComponentsExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/arch/livemodel/LiveRealmObject.java) which checks for `isValid()` in the constructor.

On the other hand, a synchronous `findFirst()` is working (so the query is correct) and `findAllAsync()` is also working correctly (and therefore [LiveRealmResults](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/architectureComponentsExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/arch/livemodel/LiveRealmResults.java)).

---

A workaround (which I currently use) is to use `findAllAsync()` and get the first entry using `firstOrNull()` in the listener (LiveData-Observer).

But it would be cleaner to return only one item when needing only one. Plus, I think there's a bug somewhere so let's fix it.

Comment: `Realm.getDefaultInstance().where` I wonder why I wrote so many articles talking about just how dangerous this construct is, but whatever

Comment: `findFirstAsync` fetches an "invalid object" at first and then calls the listener once the query is complete. However, if the item is deleted and then re-added, the query will not run again. So I don't use that method. Ever. I don't even know a single use-case that needs it, tbh. You're better off with the new `limit(1).findAllAsync()` support.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce never saw an article why this is dangerous - do you have a link? Maybe `limit()` would be an option but then I still have a list and need to get the first one so no "real" benefit. The main question is why the "reference"-implementation of `LiveRealmObject` checks for `isValid()` when it's always false at start?!

Comment: Ah. The trick is that I wrote that example and I didn't write it in findFirstAsync in mind, I'd even like it to be deprecated tbh

Comment: Haha. So, what should we do now? Mark the class as deprecated (and not working!) and close this up? An other idea would be a custom Type of `RealmResults` with only one entry (instead of having a list with size = 1 and always need to get the first one).

Comment: Oh. I don't mind the class itself. I'd want `findFirstAsync` to be deprecated. See https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/6040

Comment: What @EpicPandaForce was saying seems to be right. Came here to provide further evidence as of right now. Discussed here: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/6106#issuecomment-412866191

Comment: @mikeDOTexe seems like this relates to `findFirstAsync()` not checking the server (only using the local DB). I have this problem with a local database so this seems not the cause.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK The only way possible to do that, is using LiveRealmResults, as you said, just limit the result to 1, using `limit(1)`

Answer (score 0):

`findFirstAsync()` is returning "invalid object" because it's value we are fetching asynchronously, but inside my `onchangeListener` in `Onchange` I am getting  the first object successfully, if there are no items then in that case I am checking `isValid` which returns `false` in that case.